# Почему регулярка захватывает больше, чем необходимо?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть реуглярка:

```
'.+'
```

Есть код:

```
t('-').map((word, index) => (index ? `${word[0].toUpperCase()}${word.slice(1)}` : word)).join('')
```

Ожидание:

```
'-'
```

Реальность:

```
'-').map((word, index) => (index ? `${word[0].toUpperCase()}${word.slice(1)}` : word)).join(''
```

Comment: @Akina, там может быть строка разной длинны: t('фывфывф')

Comment: Регулярные выражения захватывают самую длинную подходящую строку. Попробуйте `'.+?'`. Знак вопроса после плюса говорит что следует выбрать самую короткую подходящую строку (https://www.phptutorial.net/php-tutorial/regex-non-greedy-lazy/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию квантификаторы (`+` в Вашем случае) являются "жадными", и покрывают максимальную последовательность. Вам нужно добавить `?`, чтобы сделать их "нежадными" (также "ленивыми"), тогда они станут покрывать минимальную последовательность.
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-questionmark

```js
const test_data = ["t('-').map((word, index) => (index ? `${word[0].toUpperCase()}${word.slice(1)}` : word)).join('')", "t('фывфывф')", "'1'2'3'4'5'"];

const regex = /'.+?'/;

for (t in test_data) {
  let m = test_data[t].match(regex);
  console.log(test_data[t], '→', m !== null ? m[0] : null);
}
```

> а если ленивых квантификаторов в используемом движке нет?

Тогда, в данном случае, я искал бы не любой символ, а "не `одинарную кавычку`":

```js
const test_data = ["t('-').map((word, index) => (index ? `${word[0].toUpperCase()}${word.slice(1)}` : word)).join('')", "t('фывфывф')", "'1'2'3'4'5'"];

const regex = /'[^']+'/;

for (t in test_data) {
  let m = test_data[t].match(regex);
  console.log(test_data[t], '→', m !== null ? m[0] : null);
}
```

Comment: а если ленивых квантификаторов в используемом движке нет?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, исправил ответ.